# pandas: fillna from a dictionary for values inside the records of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns - 'col1' & 'col2',

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1', np.nan],['2;3;5', np.nan], ['3', 'foo'], ['4;2', 'bar'], ['5;1', np.nan]], columns=['col1','col2'])

dict1 = {1:'aaa', 2:'bbb', 3:'foo', 4:'bar', 5:'ccc'}
```

and a dictionary with some values in col1 of df as keys in dictionary, I now want to replace the adjacent missing values in col2. P.S. the values in col1 are of string type while the keys in dictionary are int.

so the final answer should be like this,

```
> print(df)
[Out:]
col1        col2
----------------
   1        aaa
   2;3;5    bbb;foo;ccc
   3        foo
   4;2      bar;bbb
   5;1      ccc;aaa
```

Comment: Note that in your dictionary keys are integers, while in the dataframe col1 has strings.

Comment: @sentenceI have already mentioned that in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using for loop base on your `dict1` create the value for col2

---

```
#dict1 = {1:'aaa', 2:'bbb', 3: 'foo', 4: 'bar', 5:'ccc'} # notice here some of the key is str, some of them is int , I assuming that is typo , so I corrected it 
l=[','.join([dict1[int(y)] for y in x.split(',')]) for x in df.col1]
df['col2']=l
df
Out[61]: 
    col1         col2
0      1          aaa
1  2,3,5  bbb,foo,ccc
2      3          foo
3    4,2      bar,bbb
4    5,1      ccc,aaa
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, i edited the question (corrected the typos)

Comment: @AmanSingh notice you mentioned fillna , not assign a new columns , which is different , for example, the row 3, used to be bar, but in your expected out put changed , so I modified that to match your expected output, however, that is not fillna

Comment: thanks i now understood how to go about this problem. And I wrote fillna() because I was trying to somehow do this with fillna() method and so I thought this is the only way to go about filling in the missing values. Thanks for clarifying it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1', np.nan],['2;3;5', np.nan], ['3', 'foo'], ['4;2', 'bar'], ['5;1', np.nan]], columns=['col1','col2'])

dict1 = {1:'aaa', 2:'bbb', 3:'foo', 4:'bar', 5:'ccc'}
df['col3'] = df.col1.str.split(';').apply(lambda x: ';'.join([ dict1[int(i)] for i in x]))

print(df)
```

Result:

```
    col1 col2         col3
0      1  NaN          aaa
1  2;3;5  NaN  bbb;foo;ccc
2      3  foo          foo
3    4;2  bar      bar;bbb
4    5;1  NaN      ccc;aaa
```